# Different scope for multiple instances of Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following Angular Directive, which gets the data from the parent controller's scope. My Problem is, when the same directive is added to the same page multiple times, their scope becomes same. Whenever one of the values in any directive is changed, the same value is also changed in all the directives.

My Directive

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('memberAddress', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/Directives/memberAddress.html'
    }
});
```

memberAddress.html:

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <h3>{{addressModel.title}}</h3>
  </div>
```

Parent Design:

```
<div id="addressDiv">
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Parent controller:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('MemberController', MemberController);
MemberController.$inject = ['$scope', '$compile'];

function MemberController($scope, $compile) {
     $scope.addressModel = { title: ''}
     $scope.addAddress = function () {
           // "$scope.addressModel" Now it has some title text from UI.
           var row = angular.element(document.getElementById('addressDiv')).find('.row');
           var el = $compile("<member-address></member-address>")($scope);
           row.append(el);
     }
}
```

On calling addAddress(), it adds a "memberAddress" directive to the page first time. But when I add another addressModel.title from UI, it adds a new directive, but it changes the title in the previously added "memberAddress" directive, making title text same for all the directives.

Is there any way to prevent the other directives from changing?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve. But what's sure is that you shouldn't do DOM manipulation in a controller. If you want to add an element to a page, then add an object to an array in your model, and use ng-repeat to display every object in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by declaring new scope for every directive.

Here are the changes in Parent Controller:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('MemberController', MemberController);
MemberController.$inject = ['$scope', '$compile'];

function MemberController($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.addressModel = { title: ''}
    $scope.addAddress = function () {

       // "$scope.addressModel" Now it has some title text from UI.   

       // UPDATE - Here I created a new scope.
       var addressDirectiveScope = $scope.$new(true);
       addressDirectiveScope.addressModel = $scope.addressModel;

       var row = angular.element(document.getElementById('addressDiv')).find('.row');

       //var el = $compile("<member-address></member-address>")($scope);          
       // UPDATE - Now I passed the new scope "addressDirectiveScope" instead of "$scope" to $compile.
       var el = $compile("<member-address></member-address>")(addressDirectiveScope);
       row.append(el);
    }
 }
```

Thanks everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Set your scope in your directive not in your controller. The angular js site has an example.

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() { 
    return { 
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { customerInfo: '=info' },
        templateUrl: 'my-customer-iso.html' 
    }; 
});
```

To make it work with your code you will probably have to rewrite your controller into your directive too.

Code school covers this really well in their directive chapter in 'shaping up with angular'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an isolate scope:

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('memberAddress', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            addressModel: "@"
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/Directives/memberAddress.html'
    }
});
```

memberAddress.html:

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <h3>{{addressModel().title}}</h3>
  </div>
```

Parent Design:

```
<div id="addressDiv">
    <div class="row">
        <member-address address-model="addressModel"></member-address>
    </div>
</div>
```